# Как в html файле вызвать функцию, принимающую аргумент

Tags: python, html, django, функции, шаблонизаторы

Необходимо привязать отображение кнопки создания статьи к наличию или отсутствию права на создание статьи. Я уже понял. Попытался реализовать так, как показано ниже, но Django выдаёт ошибку, что из тэга нельзя вызывать функции (может, не совсем так, но суть примерно в этом).

```html
<div class="minarticles">
    {% if user_data.has_perm("Main.add_articles") %}
    <div class="create_article_btn">
        <a class="btn btn-lg" href="{% url 'createarticle' %}">
            <label>Создать статью</label>
            <svg width="1.6em" height="1.6em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-plus" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
              <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 3.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v4a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5H4a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1h3.5V4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5z"/>
              <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M7.5 8a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h4a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H8.5V12a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V8z"/>
            </svg>
        </a>
    </div>
    {% endif %}
...
...
...
</div>
```

Тогда, прочитав документацию, я создал свой тэг в templatetags.py:

```py
from django import template

register = template.Library()


@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def check_perm(**kwargs):
    user = kwargs['user']
    perm = kwargs['perm']
    return user.has_perm(perm)
```

А в том html файле, соответственно, переписал код  так:

```html
{% load extra_tags %}
<div class="minarticles">
    {% if check_perm user=user_data perm="Main.add_articles" %}
    <div class="create_article_btn">
        <a class="btn btn-lg" href="{% url 'createarticle' %}">
            <label>Создать статью</label>
            <svg width="1.6em" height="1.6em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-plus" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
              <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 3.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v4a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5H4a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1h3.5V4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5z"/>
              <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M7.5 8a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h4a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H8.5V12a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V8z"/>
            </svg>
        </a>
    </div>
    {% endif %}
...
...
...
</div>
```

Django же, в свою очередь, выдал примерно такую же по сути ошибку. Насколько я понял, проблема в том, что свой тэг я не могу вызвать из тэга if, но как решить эту проблему я так и не понял.
[image: Выдаваемая ошибка]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение оказалось достаточно простым:
в extra_tags.py пишем так:

```py
from django import template

register = template.Library()


@register.simple_tag()
def check_perm(user, perm):
    return user.has_perm(perm)
```

А в html файле используем этот тег отдельно от тега if, записывая результат его работы в переменную:

```html
{% load extra_tags %}
<div class="minarticles">
    {% check_perm user_data "Main.add_articles" as checkperm %}
    {% if checkperm %}
    <div class="create_article_btn">
        <a class="btn btn-lg" href="{% url 'createarticle' %}">
            <label>Создать статью</label>
            <svg width="1.6em" height="1.6em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-plus" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
              <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 3.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v4a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5H4a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1h3.5V4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5z"/>
              <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M7.5 8a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h4a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H8.5V12a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V8z"/>
            </svg>
        </a>
    </div>
    {% endif %}
...
...
...
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Вы не можете вызвать функцию, которая требует аргументов в шаблоне. Вместо этого [напишите кастомный тег](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#howto-custom-template-tags) для шаблона или фильтр.

---

[***source***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2468804/how-to-call-function-that-takes-an-argument-in-a-django-template)

Comment: Я же написал, что уже пользовался документацией, и даже привёл код написанного мною кастомного тега, но он не сработал.